# how Edittext onclick listener works?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make an activity Which will check the phone number validity.here I have a textview which shows a string "+91" and an edittext where we can input a phone number.
I have made this:--

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText ed;
TextView textv;
Button btn;
String number = "+91"; 
Context context;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    textv.setText(number);
    addlistener();
}
public void addlistener(){
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             try {  
                 String ap;
                 String edstr = ed.getText().toString();
                  String txstr= textv.getText().toString();
                   ap=txstr+edstr;
                    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance(); 
                    PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(ap, "");  
                    String internationalFormat = phoneUtil.format(numberProto,PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(phoneUtil.isValidNumber(numberProto) == true ? "Yes" : "No")
                            + internationalFormat,
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               } catch (NumberParseException e) {  
                   Toast.makeText(context,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
               }  
        }
    });
}
}
```

This code works fine..and showing the result..My requirement is when I enter the phone number in edittext it will automatically show the validation.means in my code I use a button to check the validation.I want this validation as edittext.What I have to do now????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onKeyListener` for that edittext, check if pressed key is Enter, validate number.

The code snippet:

```
ed.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            validateNumber(ed.getText().toString())
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can also use [`addTextChangedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Dhruti,I have a question..in your above code keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER...here when I press enter key of the onscreen keyboard then its working.If i press anywhere in the activity then its not showing the result.

Comment: `If i press anywhere of the activity` means? @ArijitPatra when do you want to validate?

Comment: means,when I click to the edittext an onscreen keyboard is coming,Thn I enter phone number,after that when I click "done" then it says phone number is valid or not..
But If I press anywhere of the screen without pressing done,then its not showing the result..yes,soft keyboard

Comment: @ArijitPatra "done" key of soft keyboard? for that try KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION

Comment: you are r8..actually i was thinking for keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED..that type of code..but there are no any "KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED"..

Comment: Did you try with `KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION`? @ArijitPatra

Comment: Yes madam..I have tried..But it checks everytime when I enter any number...Its okey, I can manage  from keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER..By the way u r seriously so genius..I want to be like you..

Comment: @ Dhruti madam can you solve this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725670/how-to-set-default-value-of-the-spinnerlist

Answer (score 0):

```
  youredittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            //put your validation code here
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });
```